# C# Linq to sql-classes - updated stored procedures not working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

i've got a silverlight project which uses linq to sql classes and sql server 2008 r2 with tables and stored procedures. I had to update a stored procedure because i wanted to select a additional field with datetime values.

Since there is no "update my linq to sql classes"-button as in the entity framework i had to delete and move the stored procedure to update it.

The stored procedure works fine executed on the sql server, but used in my silverlight application the new elected field gets only null values.

I created a new project with a new linq to sql classes dbml and in this project it works fine.

Maybe someone has an idea?

Regards,
float

Comment: It should be some minor error in your app. Cross check it.

Comment: I'm checking it since yesterday but i find nothing wrong.

Comment: Can you paste the code that is invoking the stored procedure of your main application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linq-to-sql-classes doesn't support this like the Entity Framework. I've added a entity data model for future use....

Answer (score 0):

Did you re-generate your DBML from with SqlMetal?

I've not used this but I have seen that there are custom add-ons to allow DBML regeneration from within Visual Studio:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37198/SqlMetalPlus-A-VS-Add-in-to-Manage-Custom-Changes

Comment: No. I used Visual Studio to generade the DBML-File. SqlMetalPlus can only be used if you start from scratch.

Comment: @float: It sounds like Visual Studio may have a bug.  The discussion [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1230203.aspx/1) may also be of use.